# offsetHeight !== scrollHeight onResize, sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm checking and comparing `body.offsetHeight` with `body.scrollHeight`.

Scaling up Window Size throws always the same values, but scaling down the Window sometimes results in "jumping" values, so I get an flickering on the Div.
Tested on Chrome 45 / and Firefox.

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement,
    offset,
    scroll;

$(window).resize(function() {
  offset = Math.max(body.offsetHeight, html.offsetHeight);
  scroll = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, html.scrollHeight);

  if (offset === scroll) {
    $(".myDiv").css("height", (offset - 155) + "px");
  } else {
    $(".myDiv").css("height", "");
  }
}).trigger("resize");
```

So what going on here?
Can somebody explain to me, what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Online Demo that illustrates my Problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/magic77/41bq62xs/

or
http://20thcenturyinterior.com/test/test.html

Comment: The above code is somewhat confusing - it's not clear what you're actually trying to do Why do you need to get both values? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hey, i´ve prepared two Demos, Links are above.

Comment: "what i´m doing wrong?" Using JS for styling in such an abusive manner :)

Comment: @meskobalazs: I Know that, but didn´t find a clean working CSS solution.

Comment: You still haven't described what you are actually trying to do. Forget all the code for a second. What is the outcome you want to have? Is it: "I want to have the background colour of my `.inner-stage` div fill up all the available space" ?

Comment: @duncanhall: Hey, yes, i want to fill up the available space :-)

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question or start a new one that actually describes what you are trying to achieve. This is much better done with CSS and does not require any javascript at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a simple rounding issue. The `offset` is rounded down, and the `scroll` is rounded up, so there is a difference of `1`. You can solve this simply:

```
if (Math.abs(offset - scroll) <= 1) {
    $(".myDiv").css("height", (offset - 155) + "px");
} else {
    $(".myDiv").css("height", "");
}
```

This is a workaround, the correct approach would be using CSS in any case. You could ask another question with your specific your problem, tagged as CSS.

Comment: Hi, your Workaround reduces the flickering. I had to increase the difference value to 8, because the difference in Firefox is much higher than in Chrome.